# Class's static struct pointer declaration in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, static

Given the following snippet:

```
   /* trie.h file */

using namespace std;
#include <list>

typedef struct tn {
         char ch;
         list<struct tn*> ptrs;
} TrieNode;

class Trie {
public:
        static const TrieNode* EMPTY;
        //... other member functions
};

/* trie.cpp file */

#include "trie.h"

// declare, define static variables of the Trie class
TrieNode* Trie::EMPTY = (TrieNode*) malloc( sizeof(TrieNode) ); // <-- seems to work fine

// the statements below seem to yield errors
Trie::EMPTY->ch = '.';
Trie::EMPTY->ptrs = nullptr;
```

I get the error: "This declaration has no storage type or type specifier" if I try to instantiate the struct member variables of the static constant variable `EMPTY`. I know storing `EMPTY`as a struct object rather than a pointer to the struct object would be easier but was curious how this would work. Thanks.

Comment: In C++, a `struct` is a type, no need for a `typedef` there. There is little or no need for `malloc` in C++, as there are operator `new` and smart pointers. C++ already has tree-like containers. They are called `std::set` and `std::map`.

Comment: `seem to yield errors` You can't have random statements outside any function in C++. `how this would work` Define a static TrieNode initialized with the data you want, then set EMPTY to point to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't put statements like `Trie::EMPTY->ch = '.';` and `Trie::EMPTY->ptrs = nullptr;` in global scope, they can only be executed inside of functions, constructors, etc.

Try something more like this instead:

```cpp
/* trie.h file */

#include <list>

struct TrieNode {
    char ch;
    std::list<TrieNode*> ptrs;
};

class Trie {
public:
    static const TrieNode* EMPTY;
    //... other member functions
};
```

```cpp
/* trie.cpp file */

#include "trie.h"

// declare, define static variables of the Trie class
static const TrieNode emptyNode{'.'};
const TrieNode* Trie::EMPTY = &emptyNode;
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/X0oq0h)

Answer (score 0):

In a namespace (outside any function) you may place only declarations.

Statements like these:

```
Trie::EMPTY->ch = '.';
Trie::EMPTY->ptrs = nullptr;
```

are not allowed to be placed in a namespace, because they are not declarations.

Moreover, this statement:

```
Trie::EMPTY->ptrs = nullptr;
```

does not make sense, because the object `ptrs` is not a pointer, and a `std::list` cannot be initialized from `nullptr`.

Pay attention to that instead of the C function `malloc()`, you should use the C++ operator `new`.

This definition:

```
TrieNode* Trie::EMPTY = (TrieNode*) malloc( sizeof(TrieNode) );
```

is also incorrect, because you forgot to specify the qualifier `const`.

It should be rewritten like this:

```
const TrieNode* Trie::EMPTY = new TrieNode { '.' };
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

typedef struct tn {
         char ch;
         std::list<struct tn*> ptrs;
} TrieNode;

class Trie {
public:
        static const TrieNode* EMPTY;
        //... other member functions
};

// the definition below must be placed in a cpp module
// it presents here only for demonstration.
const TrieNode* Trie::EMPTY = new TrieNode { '.' };

int main() 
{
    return 0;
}
```

Before exiting the program you should free the allocated memory.

Instead of the raw pointer you could use the smart pointer `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: If you use `new` to initialize the `EMPTY` pointer, then you have a memory leak unless you use an explicit finalizer to `delete` it later, such as via `atexit()`, `#pragma exit`, etc.  Using `std::unique_ptr<TrieNode>` instead of `TrieNode*` would avoid that issue.  But really, there is no good reason to use `new` at all in this situation.

Comment: @RemyLebeau If the user uses new to initialize a pointer in a cpp file then it have to remember to free it using delete. This is evident. In any case there is no memory leak because this data member has the static storage duration and the memory will be freed by the system after the program will finish its work.

Comment: "*In any case there is no memory leak*" - yes, there is, since there is a `new` without a `delete`. That is the very definition of a leak. "*because this data member has the static storage duration*" - the data member does, but the `TrieNode` it points to does not. "*and the memory will be freed by the system after the program will finish its work*" - that doesn't mean a leak doesn't occur. Imagine if this code were in a DLL that gets loaded/unloaded dynamically (ie, for an app plugin, etc).  Then the `TrieNode` would be leaked every time the DLL is unloaded, while the program is still running

Comment: @RemyLebeau Whether there will be in the program use of delete is another question. You can only make assumptions. And in nay case there is no memory leak because it is evident that it is a stand-alone simple program. As I said the system will free the used resources. There is no need to make fantasies abour dll.

Comment: "*it is evident that it is a stand-alone simple program*" - there is no such indication in the OP's post. Like you said, best not to make assumptions. And best to always `delete` what you `new`, don't leak it expecting the OS to reclaim it for you.

Comment: @RemyLebeau One again it is just your fantasies and nothing more. We do not know whether somewhere in the program there is used a call of free. He only showed how it tries to define the static data member.

Comment: whatever. I've said my piece, I'm done arguing about this. If you like writing code that doesn't clean up after itself, that is your perogative. I don't write code like that.